# Angular 6, after saving data by calling web service, change 'save' button to 'deploy' button by new functionality

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a form with some input elements, I can save this data and check some validations for check mandatory fields, on a specific situation (If form validated and data ready to deploy, I have a flag that shows this form moved to deployment department) I need to change this save button to deploy button with new functionality.

project.html :

```
<form * ngIf="selectedProject" #projectAddForm = "ngForm"(ngSubmit) = "addProject(projectAddForm)" >

<button>Save < /button>

<button *ngIf="deploymentDepartment" type = "button"(click) = "deployNewTemplate()" > Deploy < /button>

 // Some inputs elements

< /form>
```

project.ts :

```
    addProject(projectAddForm: any): void {

    this.newProject = new project();

 // Assign the input values to newProject properties

    this.projectService.addProject(this.newProject)
            .subscribe(
                (data: project) => {

                    // Imagine new added project validated and go to next deploy department
                    If(data.department = “deploymentDepartment”)

                    // How at this point change Save button by Deploy button with new functionality ??? 

                },
                (error: any) => {
                }
            );
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: project.html :

<form * ngIf="selectedProject" #projectAddForm = "ngForm"(ngSubmit) = "addProject(projectAddForm)" >

    <button>Save < /button>

    < button * ngIf="deploymentDepartment" type = "button"(click) = "deployNewTemplate()" > Deploy < /button>
.
.
. // Some inputs elements
.
.
< /form>

Comment: project.ts :

addProject(projectAddForm: any): void {

    this.newProject = new project();
.
.
.// Assign the input values to newProject properties
.
.

    this.projectService.addProject(this.newProject)
        .subscribe(
            (data: project) => {

                // Imagine new added project validated and go to next deploy department
                If(data.department = “deploymentDepartment”)

                // How at this point change Save button by Deploy button with new functionality ??? 

            }
        );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markup:

```
<button *ngIf="data?.deploymentDepartment != 'deploymentDepartment'" (click)="addProject()">Save</button>

<button *ngIf="data?.deploymentDepartment == 'deploymentDepartment'" (click)="deployNewTemplate()">Deploy</button>
```

component:

```
this.projectService.addProject(this.newProject)
    .subscribe(
        (data: project) => {
            this.data = data;
        },
        (error: any) => {
        }
    );
```

make sure to add a data property on the component.

Comment: Yessss that_guy, it is the solution, I just defined a Boolean variable 'deploymentDepartment' and checked the condition in returned data then used it on *ngIf="deploymentDepartment".

Answer (score 1):

take boolean type varaible

typescript

```
    let deploymentDepartment:boolean;

        ngOnInit() {
        this.deploymentDepartment = false;
      }
this.projectService.addProject(this.newProject)
    .subscribe(
        (data: project) => {

            // Imagine new added project validated and go to next deploy department
            If(data.department = “deploymentDepartment”)

            this.deploymentDepartment = true;

        },
        (error: any) => {
        }
    );
```

html

Use disable property binding

```
<button [disabled]="deploymentDepartment" >Save < /button>

 < button  [disabled]="!deploymentDepartment" type = "button"(click) = "deployNewTemplate()" > Deploy < /button>
```

Comment: Thanks Omair Abid,you gave me the idea, but using [disabled] attribute shows both buttons, I need Save change to Deply after true condition. so the final solution is using #ngIf instead [disabled] attribute.

Comment: @MoeinMP wellcome...but my answer was according to your question like you want to enable one button and disable other ... you should asked like hide save button and show deploy button :)